# Ansible - Regex to Ignore Specific Word

Tags: python, ansible

I have this text file:

```
text
sometext
anothertext
fewmoretext
```

How can I use regex (using ansible for this) to get all words with "text", but not the "sometext"?
I´ve tried a few combinations using the Pythex website, but without luck. I need to remove the lines that contain "text" but keep one that is specific "sometext".

I´m using this:

```
- name: Regex
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/file
    regex: "(?i)text" << Need to place the sometext to not be part here
    state: absent
```

Thanks. :)

Comment: [`(.*(?<!some)text)`](https://regex101.com/r/6tRksf/1)

Comment: @OlvinRoght is correct.  Search for `negative lookbehind assertion`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html